# php url rewrite for category and sucategory

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have both category and subcategory like following

main category is like this `www.example.com/cat/11`
sub category is also like this `www.example.com/cat/20`

i want category like this :

```
www.example.com/category-name/
```

and subcategory like :

```
www.example.com/category-name/subcategory-name
```

how can i define rules for main category and sub category and get it into this URL structure?

i have this `.htaccess` file now

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
After your question i guess you want not only 2 levels but more.

With this htaccess all requests will be handled by the index.php

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

In you index php you can parse the request uri, here an example

```
<?php
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

//if not in RootDir
$baseDirectory = '/';
$categories = explode('/', substr($path, strlen($baseDirectory)));

var_dump($categories);
//will be ['category'] for domain.tld/category
//will be ['category', 'subcategory'] for domain.tld/category/subcategory
//will be ['category', 'subcategory', 'more'] for domain.tld/category/subcategory/more
```

I think that is what you need.

Comment: category and sub category both are like www.example.com/?cat=id how can i define subcat for each cat

Comment: I changed the answer, i guess that's what you want.